# How to Make Fixed Footer to all pages - Rave

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I have a report with this design:

---

Cabec : Band1 - Body Header - Master dataBand1

---

Coluns : DataBand1 - Group Header and Row Header
Data

---

Footer : Band 2 - Bood Footer
Just to show 3 Data Field on same query.

---

All data coming of one query (Join of table Order + Items).

This reports is the Service Order and work fine when i have  little rows, but if I have many rows the footer showing in the last page. I need to show this footer in all pages. I try many options but none work.

prints of report:
http://postimg.org/image/i4xy9pf3p/

Answer (score 0):

Add the components directly to the page ( not in a band)

Answer (score 0):

You should tried to put some nearest ended position value at the "position value" there under the Band1 - Group Header Band there(For example value 80 or 90). Hopefully, it would be fullfilled your need as this manner help.Bye.